# Source Insight can't recognize multi-line macro

Tags: c, ide, source-insight

Here is a snippet:

```
#if defined(a) || \
    defined(b)
void test();
#else
void test();
#endif
```

Source Insight can't recognize multi-line macro.

It treats

```
#if defined(a) || \
    defined(b)
```

as

```
#if defined(a)
#if defined(a) || defined(b)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens with a pair of `()` i.e. `#if (defined(a) || \newline defined(b))`does cause anything on missing closing `)` ?